# Get row count of excel sheet in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sheetjs

I have an excel which has multiple sheet. Now I want to get row count for each sheet

```
 var XLSX = require('xlsx');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xlsx');
        var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
        let count = [];
        for (var sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheet_name_list.length; sheetIndex++) {
            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[sheetIndex]];
            var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
            var num_rows = range.e.r - range.s.r + 1;

            count.push({
                data_count: num_rows
            });
        }

        return count;
```

By using above script I am getting  maximum 65536 even though excel has 100000 record.

Answer (score 1):

try changing:

```
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
```

to:

```
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!fullref']);
```

Comment: after using !fullref I am getting error {"trace":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined\n    at Object.decode_range